# Update an existing resource

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Hi i'm learning Rest from many tutorials e.g ( http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html ). 
My question is: How to update existing resource ? for example i have created resource ( id =1 ) contains: id, age  and then i changed age. I created my Rest service using above tutorial but PUT method doesn't work as well as i expected.

```
Todo todo = new Todo("1", "23");  // id and age 
ClientResponse response = service.path("rest").path("todos")
    .path(todo.getId()).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .put(ClientResponse.class, todo);

String newAge = "24";
```

How can I update this existing resource ? (23 replace to newAge)

---

Ok, but i am a little bit confused... I thought that i have modify this function ?

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response putTodo(JAXBElement<Todo> todo) {
Todo c = todo.getValue();
return putAndGetResponse(c);

private Response putAndGetResponse(Todo todo) {
Response res;
if(TodoDao.instance.getModel().containsKey(todo.getId())) {
  res = Response.noContent().build();
} else {
  res = Response.created(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath()).build();
}
TodoDao.instance.getModel().put(todo.getId(), todo);
return res;
```

}

I have similar Rest service so I based on example in tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the resource, you need to implement a REST API on server-side. The code you posted is on client-side. So you can add the following method on server-side to allow PUT method:

```
@Path("todos/{id}")
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response updateAge(@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("age") int newAge) {
    // code to return the response to update the age ...

}
```